# How to get an EPSON L355 printer working on Ubuntu and How to install epson-201207w?

Tags: drivers, printing, epson

I was investigating and according to Open Printing, it is a printer that should work perfectly, however mine does not, I added it in settings and nothing, it does not print, I discovered that there is a driver called epson-201207w, but I don´t understand install it. (I'm not programmer) Can someone help me? I have also downloaded from synaptic lsp-printing and everything is still the same, I have also downloaded from synaptic lsp-printing and everything remains the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the package here: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/op/stable/debian/dists/lsb3.2/main/binary-amd64/epson-inkjet-printer-201207w_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb

Install several prerequisites:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alien at bsdmainutils libfsverity0 libjpeg62 libncurses5 librpm9 librpmbuild9 librpmio9 librpmsign9 libtinfo5 lsb lsb-core lsb-printing lsb-security ncal ncurses-term pax rpm rpm-common rpm2cpio
```

Now install the deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i epson*.deb
```

Now you should be able to select the L355 in Settings > Printing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can print now